# webdevops nginx - remove .php requirement from url

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a docker that is based off of `webdevops/php-nginx:7.2` and I am trying to configure the nginx to route requests with or without the .php extension to the appropriate file.

If `abc.php` exists, I need `/abc` and `/abc.php` to route to `abc.php`. Everything else would go to `index.php`

Current setup looks like:

`Dockerfile` contains

```
WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app/public
COPY docker/opt/docker/etc /opt/docker/etc/
```

`opt/docker/etc/nginx/conf.d/10-location-root.conf`

```
server {
  index index.html index.php;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
  }
}
```

`/app/public` contains

```
index.php
abc.php
```

Currently this configuration routes everything to `index.php` except for `/abc.php`. Trying to hit `/abc` routes to `index.php`.

Thanks :)

**Edit:** Using Ivan's answer the docker logs spam:

```
app_1  | -> Executing /opt/docker/bin/service.d/nginx.d//10-init.sh
app_1  | 2020-10-20 10:31:59,273 INFO success: nginxd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
app_1  | nginx: [emerg] unknown "_uri" variable
app_1  | 2020-10-20 10:31:59,287 INFO exited: nginxd (exit status 1; not expected)
```

Comment: Can you add your current PHP handler configuration (usually something like `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`) to your question?

Comment: The only config for location handling that I'm using is the one in the main post (10-location-root.conf). If there's anything else being set then it's probably coming from the webdevops image: https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-nginx.html - I'm new to nginx and previously had been using apache/htaccess so I'm not sure where to find where that php handler config would be

Comment: I'm not familiar with Docker, but I'm familiar with nginx and understand what nginx config you need to achieve what you want. I looked at the docs, found [this](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/tree/master/docker/php-nginx/7.2/conf/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d) on GitHub, and it seems to me that you are doing something totally wrong. Documentation mentions `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-location-root.conf`, not the `opt/docker/etc/nginx/conf.d/10-location-root.conf`. I think your modifications does not works at all.

Comment: For example, with your `server` config you won't be able to execute any PHP script at all, and if `abc.php` works as expected, it means that some other config process it (I think the default one). It seems to me that you need to modify at least two files - `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-location-root.conf` and `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-php.conf`, maybe adding a third custom one to `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/conf.d/`, lets say `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/conf.d/maps.conf`.

Comment: Can you check my first variant? Remove your `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/conf.d/10-location-root.conf`, put these two files instead and check how it works. Leave your `/app/public` content as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand how this system works, lets try the two following files for the beginning:

- `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-location-root.conf`

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}
location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
}
```

- `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-php.conf`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /<DOCUMENT_INDEX>?_url=$uri&$args;
    fastcgi_pass php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_read_timeout <PHP_TIMEOUT>;
}
```

The above configuration has one serious flaw. If the requested URI isn't the name of an existing PHP file (with or without the `.php` extension), a `$uri` internal nginx variable value will always end with `.php` due to the `rewrite` rule inside of the `@extensionless-php` named location. This would lead to the following (assuming file `/app/public/some/path.php` doesn't exist):

`/some/path` => `/index.php?_url=/some/path.php`

`/some/path.php` => `/index.php?_url=/some/path.php`

To fix this issue we can save the original `$uri` variable value inside the `extensionless-php` named location:

- `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-location-root.conf`

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}
location @extensionless-php {
    set $original_uri $uri;
    rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
}
```

- `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-php.conf`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /<DOCUMENT_INDEX>?_url=$original_uri&$args;
    fastcgi_pass php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_read_timeout <PHP_TIMEOUT>;
}
```

This configuration is better, but still has a flaw. If the requested URI ends with `.php` and there is no corresponding PHP file in the `/app/public` directory, the `$original_uri` variable won't be initialized and the `_url` query argument would be passed to backend as an empty string:

`/some/path` => `/index.php?_url=/some/path`

`/some/path.php` => `/index.php?_url=`

This could be ok for some web applications (empty `_url` query argument always meaning an invalid route), but what do we have to do if we want to get an original URI whatever it is? We can achieve it with the help of the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive (an **extremely** powerful nginx feature). However all `map` blocks should be declared outside the `server` blocks, so we would need an additional file:

- `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/conf.d/10-map.conf`

```
map $_uri $original_uri {
    ""          $uri;
    default     $_uri;
}
```

- `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-location-root.conf`

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}
location @extensionless-php {
    set $_uri $uri;
    rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
}
```

- `/opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/10-php.conf`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /<DOCUMENT_INDEX>?_url=$original_uri&$args;
    fastcgi_pass php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_read_timeout <PHP_TIMEOUT>;
}
```

This `map` block means that the `$original_uri` variable would be equal to `$uri` one if it wasn't modified (`$_uri` variable isn't initialized and empty). If the `$_uri` variable is not empty it means that the original `$uri` was modified and the `$_uri` variable now keeps its original value, so the value of the `$original_uri` variable would be set to `$_uri`. This configuration should work with any requests preserving original URI as `_url` query argument.

Comment: Hey Ivan, so when I use these snippets, all routes fail to load and my docker log is spammed with: `app_1  | -> Executing /opt/docker/bin/service.d/nginx.d//10-init.sh
app_1  | 2020-10-20 10:31:59,273 INFO success: nginxd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
app_1  | nginx: [emerg] unknown "_uri" variable
app_1  | 2020-10-20 10:31:59,287 INFO exited: nginxd (exit status 1; not expected)` - the formatting in comments is quite ugly so I will update my main post

Comment: I tried replacing the `$_uri` variable in the `10-php.conf` with just `$uri` (not sure if that's correct) and I had similar behavior before, where only `abc.php` worked and not `abc`, using just `/abc` my app seemed to crash with `[error] 65#65: *1 could not find named location "@extensionless-php", client: 172.22.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"`

Comment: @Arthur My bad, there was two typos. Corrected (see answer edit history), can you check it now?

Comment: @Arthur Thats good to hear, now we know how to modify nginx config inside the docker, but the whole configuration is not completed yet. This one was a first try to check if my approach works, but it would pass a request like `/some/path` as `_url=/some/path.php` query argument to the `index.php` script. I'll write an update to the answer to fix this and let you know.

Comment: @Arthur Phew, I finished it. Please give some feedback when you test it. Since you are new to nginx, I tried to write maximum explanation on how this configuration works. It means it is full of various english mistakes, so if you are a native english speaker, you can fix some :) (your rep should allow you to edit my answer, am I right?)

Comment: Thank you @Ivan it works perfectly. Your English is very good -  I just ended up proposing some minor grammar fixes but it's perfectly clear as is