# NGINX URL rewrite regex pattern not matching

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

After some fiddling, I had some progress.

```
                if ($query_string) {
                        rewrite /([^.]+)$ /$1.php$is_args$args break;
                }
```

The logs return

```
2020/10/31 14:51:17 [notice] 442849#0: *1 "/([^.]+)$" matches "/course/dfdfdf/dfsdfdsf", client: 220.255.213.94, server: xxx.com, request: "GET /course/dfdfdf/dfsdfdsf?dsfdsf=xxx HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.com'
```

But the rewrite still doesn't happen. Any clues?

---

I'm currently porting a php app from Apache to Nginx. Hope to get some help on the url rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite /xxx?param=value to /xxx.php?param=value

```
rewrite /^([^.]+)\? /$1.php$is_arg$args last;
```

This rewrite code is in the server block, because there are also such patterns in subdirectories to catch.

NGINX does not catch this pattern. Can someone advise?

Thanks!

Comment: `rewrite` directive works with a normalized URI which does not include the query string part, the `\?` regex part is the reason your pattern will never match any request. Moreover, `rewrite /([^.]+)$ /$1.php$is_args$args break;` on the `/course/dfdfdf/dfsdfdsf?dsfdsf=xxx` request will give you `/dfsdfdsf.php?dsfdsf=xxx`, not the `/course/dfdfdf/dfsdfdsf.php?dsfdsf=xxx`.

Comment: And one more thing, you don't need to append the query string to your rewrited URI to preserve the query arguments when you doing a rewrite via `rewrite` directive. However you need to do it when you use a `return` directive. Additionally I suggest you to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238586/no-php-extension-and-pretty-url-nginx-config-alternative/64239249#64239249) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64431202/webdevops-nginx-remove-php-requirement-from-url/64441982#64441982) answers.

Comment: Thank you. will check out the 2 links. Your advise is immensely useful.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong here, `rewrite /([^.]+)$ /$1.php$is_args$args break;` on the `/course/dfdfdf/dfsdfdsf?dsfdsf=xxx` request won't give you `/dfsdfdsf.php?dsfdsf=xxx`, `$1` capture variable would have a value of `/course/dfdfdf/dfsdfdsf` as you expected. But anyway the same thing can be achieved with a more simple `rewrite ^ $uri.php break;` rule.